# Left recursion elimination issue

Tags: left-recursion

So I have this left recursive grammar

```
E → E Op1 E2 | E2
```

As it stand, it is left recursion, so I eliminated the left recursion by putting in another step:

```
E → X E2
X → E Op1 E2 | ε
```

I have a sinking feeling however that I eliminated it wrongly, because if I trace it then the FIRST set of `E` is still going to be starting with `E`. Am I correct? Or am I missing something? This question is a part of a bigger grammar set, FYI.

Comment: Are you implementing some kind of compiler? Or it's just a generic question?

Comment: Your reasoning seems correct; however, I would consider the question as off-topic as it is primarily about theoretical computer science, not programming-related in a strict sense.

Comment: I will eventually have to implement these sets of grammar into a parser and then write a program implement those parser, so i thought it was appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

What you're missing is the second part of recursion elimination: instead of

```
X → E Op1 E2 | ε
```

you need

```
X → Op1 E2 X | ε
```